# ASP.NET Core Web API working with Foreign Keys

Tags: api, asp.net-core, post, foreign-keys

I'm developing Web Api operations for User Controller and I don't understand why I'm getting the error in the POST method :

The "PK_Section" of the PRIMARY KEY constraint was violated. Unable to insert duplicate key into dbo.Section object. Duplicate key value: (3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa4).

My IdentityUser model:

```
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserType { get; set; }
        public bool ParentsAgreement { get; set; }

        public Section BelongSection { get; set; }
```

Section Model:

```
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CoachName { get; set; }
        public string SportComplexTitle { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public ICollection<User> UsersList { get; set; }
```

DbContext:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //section
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne(s => s.BelongSection)
                .WithMany(a => a.UsersList);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
                .HasMany(s => s.UsersList)
                .WithOne(a => a.BelongSection);
        }
```

And my POST Method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Add(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                myDbContext.Users.Add(user);
                await myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                var result = await myDbContext.Users.Include(o => o.BelongSection).FirstOrDefaultAsync(o 
                     => o.Id == user.Id);
                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

So, I'm getting the error, that I can't use the Id of the existing already Section in creating User.
My Post method body is:

```
{
  "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "userName": "string",
  "normalizedUserName": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "normalizedEmail": "string",
  "emailConfirmed": true,
  "passwordHash": "string",
  "securityStamp": "string",
  "concurrencyStamp": "string",
  "phoneNumber": "string",
  "phoneNumberConfirmed": true,
  "twoFactorEnabled": true,
  "lockoutEnd": "2021-04-15T08:31:12.271Z",
  "lockoutEnabled": true,
  "accessFailedCount": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "middleName": "string",
  "surname": "string",
  "birthDate": "2021-04-15T08:31:12.271Z",
  "address": "string",
  "userType": "string",
  "parentsAgreement": true,
  "belongSection": {
    "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two ways to add existing child to parent like below:

```
_context.Section.Attach(user.BelongSection);
```

Or:

```
_context.Entry(user.BelongSection).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Be sure add `AsNoTracking()` to display the result.

Here is the whole working demo:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Add(User user)
{
    try
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        //_context.Section.Attach(user.BelongSection);
        _context.Entry(user.BelongSection).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

        _context.Users.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


        var result = await _context.Users.Include(o => o.BelongSection)
                                   .AsNoTracking()
                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o=> o.Id == user.Id);
        return result;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Note**:

Not sure what is your asp.net core version, remember to add `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`.

In asp.net core 3.x, `System.Text.Json` only supports serialization by value and throws an exception for circular references. So you need add Newtonsoft support like below:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

});
```

In .Net 5.0,you could also add Newtonsoft support. Besides,`System.Text.Json` allows seting `ReferenceHandler` to `Preserve`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0